# AJAX: I can see my Ajax's GET value sent when viewed on console, but when I print_r($_GET) on the URL page, array is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this line of code in jquery, this will be called when a certain button is clicked and the html when I print_r the GET...
To simplify, I want to transfer data from javascript to PHP without using COOKIE, preferrably using Ajax, I am still a beginner at Ajax.

```js
var variableToSend = $.session.get("date_chosen");
$.get('../pages/onsite.php', {the_date: variableToSend});
```

```html
<div><?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET); ?></div>
```

[You can see my screenshot in here, the empty array and the console that shows my ajax is "successful"(i think), but an empty array is shown when I print_r the get value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJtgh.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you're visiting http://localhost/dcwd_newservice_v2/pages/onsite.php without any query parameters - which is why the `$_GET` array is empty.

Parallell to this a completely separate request is being made behind the curtains by jQuery to http://localhost/dcwd_newservice_v2/pages/onsite.php?the_date=2017-04-11. This will not affect what you are seeing in your browser window - because what you are seeing in your browser window is static text generated by the server when you visited the site without any query parameter. If you want the site to update, then you could for example manipulate the DOM via javascript based on the response you get.

If you inspect the response of that AJAX request in chrome devtools, you will probably see PHP dumping what you are expecting to see in your `$_GET` variable (`the_date => 2017-04-11`).

You can also try making the same request yourself, to see it live in the browser: http://localhost/dcwd_newservice_v2/pages/onsite.php?the_date=2017-04-11

Comment: so how should I do this using query parameters?

when you say manipuate the DOM, does it includes refreshing the page to get a new URL?

I am still a beginner at Ajax, trying to find the best way to integrate ajax with jquery, mysql, and php

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not very clear. You have already achieved just passing data from javascript to the server. I would suggest creating a separate script, say perhaps "api/index.php" that bridges the client and the server.  For example `<?php echo json_encode($_GET);`. Then in your javascript you can do something like `$.get('http://localhost/dcwd_newservice_v2/api/', {message: 'Hello world'}, function(data) { console.log(data); });`. Use the callback function to do whatever with the server response on the client side - and the php scrip to eg manipulate the database.